# jQuery gallery with imageFUpload

Tags: ajax, javascript

here's the code of kartinkin.php file:

```
<?php

  $node = node_load(707);
  node_view($node);
  //$index = $_GET['index'];
  //dpm($node);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.small-images a').click(function(e) {
      $.get("http://myadress.org/kartinki.php", {"index": index});
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });

</script>

<?php $index = $_GET['index']; dpm($index); ?>

<div class="imba-slider">
  <a class="left-arrow" href="javascript: void(0);">#</a>
  <a class="right-arrow" href="javascript: void(0);">#</a>

  <div id="big-image-slider">
    <?php if ($index == 0): ?>
      <?php print theme_imagecache('imba', $node->field_pics[0]['filepath']); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php print theme_imagecache('imba', $node->field_pics[$index]['filepath']); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!--/big-image-slider-->

  <div class="small-images">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= count($node->field_pics); $i++) { ?>
      <a href="?index=<?php print $i; ?>"><?php print theme_imagecache('230x130', $node->field_pics[$i]['filepath']); ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div><!--/small-images-->
</div><!--/imba-slider-->
```

I have included that file with `include_once()` inside a node.

**PROBLEM.** When i click on small-image it reloads the page and after reload my big image changes. With a code above i've tried to do it without a page reload, i even write `e.preventDefault();` But still after clicking on a preview image it reloads the page. How can i make big image changing without reload?

Comment: I don't see index being defined anywhere but you're using it in: {"index": index}

Comment: I am trying to pass that "index" to a php variable $index = $_GET['index']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several issues here:

1. PHP runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client's browser so they don't know about eachothers variables.
2. You're not doing anything with your $.get(..) results, you need to do something with the results of the ajax get request in a success or complete callback.
3. You're calling a URL to a full page, i'm assuming you want just the image.

If your image names follow the naming convention I see where the thumbnails use `/230x130/` in the path and the larger image uses `/imba/` instead, then use the code below instead of your current click event:

```
slideShowIndex = 0;

$('#big-image-slider img.imagecache-imba').load(function(){
  hideSlideLoader();
});


$('.small-images a').click(function(sender){
  sender.preventDefault();
  showSlideLoader();
  var lnk = $(this);
  slideShowIndex = $('.small-images a').index(lnk);
  var imgUrl = lnk.find('img').attr('src').replace('/230x130/','/imba/');
  $('#big-image-slider img.imagecache-imba').attr('src', imgUrl);
  return false;
});

function showSlideLoader() {
  //$('#big-image-slider').html('<img class="loader" src="/sites/all/themes/antisunna/img/ajax-loader.gif" />') 
  var loader = $('#big-image-slider .loader');
  if(!loader.length) {
    console.log('creating loader');
    loader = $('<img class="loader" src="/sites/all/themes/antisunna/img/ajax-loader.gif" />')
    $('#big-image-slider').append(loader);
  }
  $('#big-image-slider .imagecache-imba').hide();
  loader.show();
}

function hideSlideLoader() {
  $('#big-image-slider .loader').hide();
  $('#big-image-slider .imagecache-imba').show();  

}

$('.left-arrow').click(function(){
  if(slideShowIndex > 0) {
    moveSlideIndex(slideShowIndex--);
  }  
});


$('.right-arrow').click(function(){
  if(slideShowIndex < ($('.small-images a').length - 1)) {
    moveSlideIndex(slideShowIndex++);
  }  
});


function moveSlideIndex(index) {
  $('.small-images a:eq(' + slideShowIndex + ')').click();
}
```

Comment: nice man, it works! Can you help me with a left and right arrows now? i would really appreciate it also :)) PS why you have used preventDefault() with return false, isn't preventDefault() enough to remove href click event?

Comment: Should the arrows only cycle through the thumbnail images below the larger image? If so, what do you want to do with the previous arrow if you're on the first image?

Comment: yes, only cycle through the thumb images, when we are on the first image - it does nothing, same with the last one.

Comment: I update the script to work with the arrows.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I'm also trying to implement loader image now: $('#big-image-slider').html('<img class="loader" src="/sites/all/themes/antisunna/img/ajax-loader.gif" />') should i put it right before the image appears itself?

Comment: See my updates, you need to add a new event for the load event on the large image. That will determine when to hide the "loader". Also see the caveats for using the "load" event on images: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: i've found a downside of it... on my big preview div imagecache presets won't apply at all :(